# How to pass user define table type of sql server as a parameter to a store procedure from java

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am facing following problem

I am using Spring jdbc and database is SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a data type define in SQL server

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EIMREQUESTLOG] AS TABLE(
        [EIMREQUESTID] [bigint] NULL,
        [EIMREQUESTDETAILID] [bigint] NULL,
        [REQUESTPACKET] [xml] NULL,
        [REQUESTHEADER] [xml] NULL
    )
```

and store procedure that uses this data type

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[EIMRequestPacket_Log] 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @pEIMRequestLog DBO.EIMREQUESTLOG readonly,
        @pRequestTypeId smallint = NULL,
        @pIsInternal char(1) = '0'
    AS
    DECLARE
     @vCreated datetime
    BEGIN
    -------
    END
```

#### My implementation

**GenericStruct.java**

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Struct;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class GenericStruct implements Struct 
    {
       private Object [] attributes = null;
       private String typeName = null;

       /*
        * Constructor
        */
       public GenericStruct() { }

       public GenericStruct(String name, Object [] obj)
       {
          typeName = name;
          attributes = obj;
       }
       public String getSQLTypeName()
       {
          return typeName;
       }
       public Object [] getAttributes()
       {
          return attributes;
       }
       public Object [] getAttributes(Map> map) throws SQLException
       {
          // this class shouldn't be used if there are elements
          // that need customized type mapping.
          return attributes;
       }
       public void setAttributes(Object [] objArray)
       {
          attributes = objArray;
       }
       public void setSQLTypeName(String name)
       {
          typeName = name;
       }
    }
```

**CustomStoredProcedure.java**

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

    public class CustomStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {
        public CustomStoredProcedure(DataSource ds, String procName, SqlParameter[] params) {
            setDataSource(ds);
              setSql(procName);
            for (SqlParameter param: params) {
                declareParameter(param);
            }
            compile();
        }

        public Map execute(Map inputMap) {
           if(inputMap == null) {
               inputMap = new HashMap();
           }
           return super.execute(inputMap);
        }
    }
```

**EIMRequestDAOImpl.java**

```
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Types;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlReturnResultSet;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository("eimRequestDAO")
    public class EimRequestsDAOImpl extends AbstractJpaDAOImpl
            implements EimRequestsDAO {
        private static Logger logger = Utils.getLogger(EimRequestsDAOImpl.class);

        @Autowired(required = true)
        private DataSource dataSource;

        public String getEimRequestPackageLog(long requestId,int requestDetailId, String xmlPacket,String xmlHeader) {

            final String batchNo="";
            Map results = null;
            try {
                final String PARAM = "@pEIMRequestLog";
                Object[] attributes = new Object[]{requestId,requestDetailId,xmlPacket,xmlHeader};
                GenericStruct eimRequestLog = new GenericStruct();
                eimRequestLog.setSQLTypeName("EIMREQUESTLOG");
                eimRequestLog.setAttributes(attributes);
                Map inputMap = new HashMap();
                inputMap.put(PARAM, eimRequestLog);
                results = new CustomStoredProcedure(dataSource,
                        "EIMRequestPacket_Log", new SqlParameter[] {
                                new SqlReturnResultSet("EimRequest",
                                        new RowMapper() {
                                            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs,
                                                    int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                                                return rs.getString("BATCHNO");
                                            }
                                        }),
                                new SqlParameter(PARAM, Types.STRUCT)})
                        .execute(inputMap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return batchNo;
        }
    }
```

** TestServiceImpl.java**

```
    @Transactional
        public String saveRequest() throws EimTopUpException {
            long requestId = 1000;
            int requestDetailId = 3;
            String xmlPacket = "";
            String xmlHeader = "";
            return eimRequestDAO.getEimRequestPackageLog(requestId,
                    requestDetailId, xmlPacket,xmlHeader);
        }
```

but when i call this method it gives following exception

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call EIMRequestPacket_Log(?)}]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The conversion from UNKNOWN to STRUCT is unsupported.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to STRUCT is unsupported.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy12.saveRequest(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:36)
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to STRUCT is unsupported
```

I could not solve the problem that how to pass user define table type of sql server from java.

Comment: For anyone who shows up here in a search, see the comments in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545844/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-user-defined-table-type-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedur