# Passing a user-defined table type to a SQL Server stored procedure using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, user-defined-types

We've got this User-Defined-Table Type in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[INITVALS_MSG] AS TABLE(
    [SDate] [decimal](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [EDate] [decimal](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PlantCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [LoadType] [nchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Asset] [bigint] NOT NULL
)
```

and a Stored Procedure which takes that table as input:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterInitAssets]
    @initmsg INITVALS_MSG ReadOnly
AS
BEGIN
    ...
```

Now, I need to call this procedure from java. Is it possible to do such a thing? Does JDBC support this?

--------EDIT
I have a corresponding class in java for that type:

```
public class DBInitialAsset {
    private Integer sDate;
    private Integer eDate;
    private String plantCode;
    private String loadType;
    private Integer asset;

    public DBInitialAsset() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is now possible. Version 6.0 of Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server added support for table-valued parameters.

The following code sample shows how to

- use a `SQLServerDataTable` object to hold the table data to be passed, and
- call the `SQLServerCallableStatement#setStructured` method to pass that table to the stored procedure.

```java
SQLServerDataTable sourceDataTable = new SQLServerDataTable();   
sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("SDate", java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);
sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("EDate", java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);
sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("PlantCode", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR);
sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("LoadType", java.sql.Types.NCHAR);
sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("Asset", java.sql.Types.BIGINT);

// sample data
sourceDataTable.addRow(123, 234, "Plant1", "Type1", 123234);   
sourceDataTable.addRow(456, 789, "Plant2", "Type2", 456789);   

try (CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{CALL dbo.RegisterInitAssets (?)}")) {
    ((SQLServerCallableStatement) cs).setStructured(1, "dbo.INITVALS_MSG", sourceDataTable);
    boolean resultSetReturned = cs.execute();
    if (resultSetReturned) {
        try (ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet()) {
            rs.next();
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, see the following MSDN article:

[Using Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt651781(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: 3 year old question! I used xml parameters to solve this issue back then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is there any way to the exact same with using Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Was helpful for me, using spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc. Also may be required CallableStatement #isWrapperFor() and #unWrap(), as your classpath could be using a proxy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/unwrap-method-sqlservercallablestatement?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @SJ.Jafari can I use jdbc to store data in two tables of different databases, if we change table one second table in second database should also change ...... I used  2 connection obj and tried fetching all data from table one and inserted in table two but that cause one issue; in table two the data always generate duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call dbo.RegisterInitAssets(?)}");
statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);//you can skip this if procedure won't return anything
statement.setObject(2, new InitvalsMsg()); //I hope you some kind of representation of this table in your project
statement.execute();

ResultSet set = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(1);//skip it too if its not returning anything
```

Comment: Well, I followed what you are suggesting and I get: {com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.}

Comment: I edited the question and added the corresponding class, please take a look.

Comment: I've edited my answer, there was parameter number missing, try it now

Comment: I investigated a lot on this and what I found eventually is that it is not possible to pass TVPs using JDBC, take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/04/03/how-would-you-use-table-valued-parameters-tvp.aspx

Comment: This answer looks like it applies to Oracle, not Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @SJ.Jafari re: *"it is not possible ..."* - It is now. See my answer.