# How to pass StringArrayType in Java to a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014. This stored procedure takes a parameter of type `StringArrayType`.
This is the stored procedure script to modify it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_something] @list_a StringArrayType READONLY
AS  
    DECLARE @sol INT = 0
    DECLARE @MAXOnlineProcesses INT = 0
BEGIN  

    SET @sol = ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                          FROM @list_a 
                          WHERE Category not in ( SELECT AgentHostName 
                                                  FROM [dbo].[TableA]
                                                  WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND , [CurrentRequestTime] , GETDATE()) <  
                                                              ( [RequestsInterval] * ( SELECT [Value] 
                                                                                       FROM [ATC].[dbo].[TableB] WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                                                                       WHERE [Parameter] = 'RemoveProcessAfterNumRequests'))))
    SELECT @sol as [AA], 
    (@sol - @MAXOnlineProcesses) as [BB]
END
```

I have a code in .Net which set DataTable variable in order to execute this stored procedure:

```
Dim dtable As DataTable = New DataTable
        Try
            Dim sqlConnection As String = "server=" & SQLServerName & ";uid=" & SQLUserID & ";pwd=" & SQLpassword & ";database=" & SQLDBName
            dtable.Columns.Add("Category")
            For Each item As String In list
                dtable.Rows.Add(item)
            Next

            Using cnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnection)
                Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp_something", cnn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@list_a", dtable)
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 30
                    Using adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Using ds As New DataSet
                            adapter.Fill(ds)
                            Dim Host2Wait As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("BB")
                            If Host2Wait > 0 Then
                             //some code
                            End If
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            // some code
            Return False
        End Try
```

Now, I need to call this stored procedure using Java code. How can I do that? What can I pass the stored procedure in java that will be set as `StringArrayType`? I saw some questions regarding what can replace .Net `DataTable` in java, but I couldn't crack how to do it using WebRowSet.

I tried JdbcRowSet and WebRowSet, but I think it's not the correct direction.

Comment: I'm assuming that the StringArrayType is a User-Defined-Table-Type in which case this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545844/passing-a-user-defined-table-type-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-jdbc

Comment: You need to use the Microsoft JDBC driver to pass TVPs. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters) for example code.

Comment: Also, the client type for the TVP parameter value needs to be `SQLServerDataTable`.

Comment: Also you can always write a TSQL batch where you pass a delimited string or JSON array, parse it, and load a TVP on the server side, and then call the procedure.  This is the only option for some client libraries.